# How to prove that the limit of a polynomial at infinity is always equal to the limit of the highest order term in the polynomial?

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

In following Spivak's Calculus chapter 5 on limits, I went through the proof of the following theorem:

> If $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x) = l$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to a}
> > g(x)=m$, then
>
> (1) $\lim\limits_{x \to a} (f+g)(x) = l + m$
>
> (2) $\lim\limits_{x \to a} (f \cdot g)(x) = l \cdot m$
>
> Moreover, if $m \neq 0$, then
>
> (3) $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \left ( \frac{1}{g}\right ) (x) =
> > \frac{1}{m}$

Subsequently, I encountered the limit of a polynomial at infinity, ie

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)$$

where $f$ is a polynomial, ie a function of form

$$f(x) = a_n x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ... + a_0$$

**I have always had it in my mind that when we take the limit of such a function, the highest order term "dominates"**, ie the the limit of the function is equal to the limit of the term $a_n x^n$, which is $\pm \infty$ depending on the sign of $a_n$.

**I'd like to prove this.**

**Let me first try to prove the following more general result**

> Let
> $$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} h(x) = \infty$$
>
> $$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} g(x) = m>0$$
>
> Then $$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} h(x)g(x) = \infty$$

Since $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} h(x) = \infty$, then

$$\forall M_1>0\ \exists N_1>0\ \forall x,\ x>N_1\ \implies h(x)>M_1\tag{1}$$

Also, since $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} g(x) = m$, we have

$$\forall \epsilon>0\ \exists N_2>0\ \forall x,\ x>N_2\ \implies m-\epsilon<g(x)<m+\epsilon\tag{2}$$

For any $M>0$, let $M_1>0$ and $0<\epsilon<m$ such that $M_1(m-\epsilon)=M$.

Then, as per $(1)$ and $(2)$ there exist $N_1$ and $N_2$ such that

$$\forall x,\ x>N_1\ \implies h(x)>M_1$$

$$\forall x,\ x>N_2\ \implies m-\epsilon<g(x)<m+\epsilon$$

Let $N=max(N_1, N_2)$.

Then

$$\forall x,\ x>N \implies h(x)g(x)>M_1(m-\epsilon)=M>0$$

We've thus shown that

$$\forall M>0\ \exists N>0\ \forall x,\ x>N \implies h(x)g(x)>M$$

Thus

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} h(x)g(x) = \infty$$

**Is this proof correct?** If it is, then we can apply its conclusion to $f(x)$.

We can rewrite $f$ as

$$f(x) = a_n x^n \left (1+ \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}\frac{1}{x}+\frac{a_{n-2}}{a_n}\frac{1}{x^2}+...+\frac{a_0}{x^n}\right)$$

Let's consider the case where $a_n>0$.

$f$ is the product of the following two functions $h$ and $g$:

$$h(x) = a_n x^n$$

$$g(x) = \left (1+ \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}\frac{1}{x}+\frac{a_{n-2}}{a_n}\frac{1}{x^2}+...+\frac{a_0}{x^n}\right)$$

Their limits at infinity are

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} h(x) = \infty$$

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} g(x) = 1$$

Therefore,

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} h(x)g(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} h(x) =  \infty$$

Comment: In your theorem with $\infty$ and $m$ you need $m \ne 0$.

Comment: For the specific result I am proving, I guess I need $m>0$, correct?

I could prove another result when $m<0$, namely that the limit equals $-\infty$.